# MY computer speakers / earphone producing "zzzzh" noise only in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sound-card, speakers

MY computer speakers and headphone producing "zzzzzhhh" noise during using windows. The noise starts when I get into windows login screen but no problems untill login screen.

But in linux there is no problems and until windows boots .. no problem. The noise occurs only when I using windows session but good (remains silent) at other OSes.

Why? Please give a solution.

OS: Windows 7 x64 Ultimate 
Motherboard: Intel DG41RQ 
Sound Card: In built

Comment: Possibility you may have microphone enabled and the speaker are feeding the microphone to the speaker...? (note: Microphone enabled does not mean microphone are connected) Try "muting" your microphone by going to your speaker icon on bottom right hand corner, "Playback Devices" - choose your speaker and click Properties - and under "Levels" tab, mute the microphone and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- I think the solution is obvious, ditch Windows and use Linux [image: tongue]
- Download and install the [Realtek* ALC Audio Driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19472) (AUD_Vista_Win7_6.0.1.6201_PV.exe) from Intel

Comment: The problem is not login sound..... :) .. .. the 3rd solution looks good

Comment: It's most likely a driver issue. Did this just start happening or has it occurred since Win7 was installed?

Comment: it started 5 months ago.. but i installed windows 2 years ago. That means for 1.5 years there is no issue..

Comment: Sounds like a new driver may have a bug and it was delivered via automatic update.